# How do I train my kneser-ney model for next word prediction to estimate my discount parameters

Tags: r, nlp

I am working on a project to predict the next word in a text. I have used the `quanteda` package in R to generate tri-grams and bi-grams. I am aware that we need to maximize the probability of the sentences that are in the held out test set. However I am not sure how to go about it. Any help would be great :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We ask that when you ask a question like this you give a reproducible example showing where you've made an attempt to answer your own question and run into a problem. Otherwise the question will likely be closed for being too broad or being a code-writing request.

Comment: Hello, I would like to add the tables of trigrams and bigrams that I have created. WOuld that be something satisfying the requirements? As far as the code is concerned, I am looking for the algorithm to implement my idea of maximizing the values of parameter, d and lambda model

Answer (score 0):

Next word prediction in R is the capstone project for the Coursera JHU Data Science MOOC series, so you can find at least dozens of examples of how to do this in R published online by prior students.

An excerpt from [one example](https://github.com/stephenfranklin/nlp-word-prediction/blob/master/word-predict/word_prediction.R) is:

```
predict_trigrams <- function(input.dt, ngram4.dt){
    ### Returns top3grams, column w4 by frequency.
setkey(ngram4.dt,w1,w2,w3)
top3grams <- ngram4.dt[.(input.dt$w1,input.dt$w2,input.dt$w3)]
top3grams <- top3grams[order(-tots)]
top3grams$w4
}

predict_bigrams <- function(input.dt, ngram4.dt){
    ### Compare the input bigram (last two words) 
    ### to every combo of bigrams: columns 1:2, 1:3, 2:3.
    ### Returns top_bigrams, w3 & w4 by frequency (w3 renamed to w4).

    ### bigrams input w2 & w3 to w1 & w2, returning w3 ###
    setkey(ngram4.dt,w1,w2)
    ### binary search .() is alias for list()
    top12grams <- ngram4.dt[.(input.dt$w2,input.dt$w3)]
    top12grams <- top12grams[,ngrams:=NULL]
    top12grams <- top12grams[,w4:=NULL]
    setkey(top12grams,w1,w2,w3)
    top12s <- top12grams[,sum(tots),by=w3]
    top12s <- top12s[order(-V1)]

    ### bigrams input w2 & w3 to w2 & w3, returning w4 ###
    setkey(ngram4.dt,w2,w3)
    ### binary search .() is alias for list()
    top23grams <- ngram4.dt[.(input.dt$w2,input.dt$w3)]
    top23grams <- top23grams[,ngrams:=NULL]
    top23grams <- top23grams[,w1:=NULL]
    setkey(top23grams,w2,w3,w4)
    top23s <- top23grams[,sum(tots),by=w4]
    top23s <- top23s[order(-V1)]

    ### Combine results ###
    setnames(top12s, "w3", "w4")
    top_bigrams <- rbind(top12s,top23s)
    top_bigrams <- top_bigrams[,sum(V1),by=w4]
    top_bigrams <- top_bigrams[order(-V1)]
    top_bigrams$w4
}

pred1 <- function(w,input.dt,ngram4.dt){
    ### To be used within `predict_unigrams()`.
    ### w is the column to predict from: "w1", "w2", or "w3"
    ### the subsequent column will be returned by frequency.
    setkeyv(ngram4.dt,w)  ## setkeyv() for variables
    ### binary search .() is alias for list()
    top1grams <- ngram4.dt[.(input.dt[,w3])]
    top1grams <- top1grams[,ngrams:=NULL]
    if(w=="w3"){
        ww <- "w4"
        top1grams <- top1grams[,w1:=NULL]
        top1grams <- top1grams[,w2:=NULL]
    }
    if(w=="w2"){
        ww <- "w3"
        top1grams <- top1grams[,w1:=NULL]
        top1grams <- top1grams[,w4:=NULL]
    }
    if(w=="w1"){
        ww <- "w2"
        top1grams <- top1grams[,w3:=NULL]
        top1grams <- top1grams[,w4:=NULL]
    }
    top1s <- top1grams[,sum(tots),by=ww]
    top1s <- top1s[order(-V1)]
    setnames(top1s, ww, "w4")
    top1s  
}

predict_unigrams <- function(input.dt, ngram4.dt){
    ### Requires function `pred1()`.
    ### Compare the input unigram (last word) 
    ### to every combo of unigrams: columns 1, 2, & 3.
    ### Returns top_unigrams: w2, w3, w4 by frequency (w2 & w3 renamed to w4).

    ### predict w4 from w3 ###
    top1s4 <- pred1("w3",input.dt,ngram4.dt)
    #head(top1s4)
    ### predict w3 from w2 ###
    top1s3 <- pred1("w2",input.dt,ngram4.dt)
    #head(top1s3)
    ### predict w2 from w1 ###
    top1s2 <- pred1("w1",input.dt,ngram4.dt)
    #head(top1s2)
    ### Combine results ###
    top_unigrams <- rbind(top1s4,top1s3)
    top_unigrams <- rbind(top_unigrams,top1s2)
    top_unigrams <- top_unigrams[,sum(V1),by=(w4)]
    top_unigrams <- top_unigrams[order(-V1)]
    top_unigrams$w4
}
```

Having said that, if you're doing this for that course or any other, it really would've been a better learning experience if you tried to figure it out for yourself based on what you learned in the course.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I understand that the above example predicts the next word by means of a look up table and looking for the next most frequent word. However, I was looking for an example of the kneser-ney implementation which deals with the issue of context better.